# Positioning of navbar over image in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image, navbar

I am trying to put an image behind my navbar and have the navbar sit on the lower part of the image. I've tried adding position data to .navbar but it doesn't move it down. In addition, the bottom half of the image below the navbar is cut off. If I add height info to image the full image shows up, but in responsive mode the nav menus and main page overlap. 
I've tried putting image as background to .bg-light and as image in html before the navbar.

I'm new to Bootstrap (which btw I really like), and any help appreciated.

```css
.bg-light{
 background-image:url("http://www.peterrussell.com/images/header2.jpg")!important; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PR</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item dropdown menubar">
   
  <!--  various menu contents omitted for clarity -->
   
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>  
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Not quite sure what you require? It looks like the code is already in snippet. I should probably have included more of the dropdowns so you can see placing of menu bar. Current snippet only shows how image is cut off.

Comment: Sorry. Got it. You mean to copy into my page.

Comment: Code looks same - apart from layout. I had js scripts at foot of page. Still shows up same.  What I am ultimately working towards is something like https://www.peterrussell.com  What I got so far is https://www.thestoryofi.com/test/bootstrap.php with code as above. I've modified bootstrap to make menus semi-transparent, but this hasn't affected layout.

Comment: ElfRock, can you elaborate on your solution?  I just starting a project that I will have to take the same approach where the vertical menu lines up with the bottom of the banner image.  Thank you

Comment: @JerryWarra In the end I fiddled around with `transform: translateY();` to get things in the right place. But the solution was very specific to my code, so don't think I can help.